# Does Laravel 4.2 and 5.2 supports PHP 7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, php-7

I am working on project which was created using Laravel 4.2 and i am curious to know, if Laravel 4.2 and Laravel 5.2 , supports PHP 7 or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Starting from 4.2.20 Laravel supports PHP7

[@laravelphp](https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/791302938027184128) tweet:

> A special release of Laravel 4.2 has been made (4.2.20) to provide PHP
>   7 support. Also updates base Symfony components to 2.7.

---

<s>From one of [Laravel issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11329):</s>

> Laravel 5.1 is the first version of Laravel to support PHP 7.

and

> Laravel 4.2, and the related symfony version will never get PHP 7 support.

Graham Campbell is the main [Laravel contributor](https://github.com/laravel/framework/graphs/contributors) after Taylor Otwell, so this info is pretty reliable.

Comment: Laravel 4.2 *does* now support PHP7, so this accepted answer is now out of date. It was accurate when it was written, but things appear to have changed.

Comment: Thank you @Simba for this notification, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As from today Laravel 4.2 got support for PHP 7. So you can upgrade to 4.2.20 to use it in PHP 7